# Access a web service from a different network

Tags: java, service, web, public

A simple description of our architecture for the school project we are doing:
-we have a data warehouse to compile data from all clients
-clients are using a locally deployed web application.

Each client would have a local web application for it to stand on its own even without internet connection.

We would like to create a web service that will serve as connection for the client and the data warehouse. Our issue here is that the data warehouse and the clients are not in the same network.

OUR QUESTION: How do we make the web service available public so that clients can use it even if they are not in the same network with the data warehouse.

Comment: for me it seems a network issue and not an application issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we make the web service available public so that clients can
>   use it even if they are not in the same network with the data
>   warehouse.

You might want to consider opening the web service to the internet, consult with your ISP if they have restrictions, tell them to open the port no. (e.g. 8080) of the web service you're running. If you have routers, make sure you forward the traffic to the correct port.

Now your clients can consume it wherever they may be. You just need to provide them the external IP address and the port no, basically the URL of your web service.

Take note. This is an insecure way of sharing web services. Later on, you might want to consider a Virtual Private Network (VPN) solution for your clients to connect to. There's huge danger in opening it to the wild.

Comment: sorry if this will be a stupid question. opening of ports can only be done by my ISP?

Comment: It depends. First, check what your external IP is, then try accessing your service using that external IP. If it's accessible, then you're lucky.

Comment: I think the problem that we would then be facing is having a static IP address to open a port for. I think implementing this architecture for our SCHOOL project would require too \much resources.

Comment: For the purpose of a school project, you can use dynamic IPs, just subscribe to a free domain name. Use that free domain in place of the IP address.

Comment: for example here is our web service deployed locally http://localhost:51197/HelloWorldApplication/test-resbeans.html I will just replace localhost with my external IP?